# Find an inner product on $C[0,1]$ such that {$2^{1/2}\sin(n\pi x):n\ge 1$} is an orthonormal set

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Find an inner product on $C[0,1]$ such that {$2^{1/2}\sin(n\pi x):n\ge 1$} is an orthonormal set and verify that this set is orthonormal for your choice of inner product.

I'm pretty much stumped for this one, any input would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Consider the usual inner product. Are they orthogonal with respect to it? What about orthonormal? If either is false, is there anything obvious you can do for a quick and easy fix?

Comment: Im having trouble comprehending how to take the inner product of {$2^{1/2}sin(n\pi x): n \ge 1$}, so far we have only been working with normed vector spaces @anon

Comment: Have you been introduced to any inner product on a function space whatsoever? Like, [the one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Functions) involving an integral of a product of two functions?

Comment: @anon not really, I'm trying to get ahead on some homework but my text doesn't provide any examples of this kind

Comment: Sounds like a strange homework-text combination. Check that $(f,g)\mapsto \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$ is an inner product on $C[0,1]$ (the "usual" one I spoke of), then review my first comment.

Comment: @anon Thanks, ill try it, is it ok if I refer back to you if I get stuck?

Comment: Sure, though I'm not always here 24/7. If you see a message saying something about moving discussion to chat, don't feel bad about ignoring it.

Comment: What is the text?

Answer (score 1):

The world's favorite inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$ does the job. (As the world's favorite anon already said.) The key point is 
$$2\sin \pi n x \sin \pi m x = \begin{cases} 1-\cos 2\pi nx,\quad &m=n \\ 
\cos \pi(n-m)x -  \cos \pi(n+m)x, \quad &m\ne n\end{cases}$$ 
where all cosines integrate to $0$ over $[0,1]$. Strictly speaking, the first line is a special case of the second, but for purpose of integration one has to separate the two cases anyway.